# How to plan diagram states of this machine?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, state-machines, system

How can I design a tracking system that receives two numbers x and y parallel, bit per cycle, starting LSB, and emitting a "1" when x>2y ?

I know that "2y" is like "y" with zero in right side .. But I still can not plan diagram Conditions.

Note: You need to do it with less than 5 states.

Comment: What do you mean by "parallel, bit per cycle"? Do you mean "serial, one bit per cycle"?

Answer (score 1):

First consider the case where your machine is simply comparing x and y. Initially your state will be that x and y are equal. As you receive data LSB first, any bit received will be more significant than bits received so far. So you have three states { x=y, x>y and y>x } which are transitioned between as data is received.

You know that the difference between this machine and the machine you want is that one of the inputs is shifted by one bit. So can you convert this machine so one if the inputs is delayed by one clock cycle using two more states?

Comment: Hwo can i do it?

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask for complete solutions. We're happy to help you work it out yourself and Pete has given you a lot of useful hints, but you have to s-how you're doing the work yourself.